# Django allauth login/logout error: is_safe_url() missing 1 required positional argument 'allowed_hosts'

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'v implemented django-allauth on my local website for handling register/login/... things but i keep getting this error when try to login or logout:

```
TypeError at /accounts/login/
is_safe_url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'allowed_hosts'
```

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

all settings mentioned in [here](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) have been implied.

here is [full traceback](http://dpaste.com/2FKFEDV)

allauth version: 0.39

django version: 2.2.2

Comment: Can you please share the *full* traceback?

Comment: I think your `django-allauth` is not compatible with your `django` version

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added

Comment: @KostasCharitidis versions added

Comment: Your code worked fine in my machine, which is ArchLinux. And versions are Django==2.2.4 &
django-allauth==0.39.1

Comment: Try adding ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost'] in settings.py

Comment: @RohitSharma did not help!

Answer (score 0):

After a few searches I found the solution. When I updated the allauth from "pip" I've forgotten to download new allauth folder from github. So my files where the older ones but my version was new. Amateur job! :)